# No cached version of io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4 available for offline mode

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am facing this issue. Tried many things but no success.

"No cached version of io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4 available for offline mode"

I checked:

1. Internet connection by NO proxy, auto proxy and by entering address and port.
2. File > Invalidates chache and restart
3. Rebuild and Restart android studio
4. Check for plugin fabric but not found.

How to solve io.fabric error ? Please comment.

Is io.fabric obsolete? What is solution if app contains it?

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is one more option which is left to try check if the offline mode is enabled or not. below one is offline. If offline then change this to online and sync again
[image]